# Webpack plugins definePlugin and CommonsPlugin

Tags: webpack

Im pretty new to webpack (and process managers).  Is it possible for someone to please help me and explain these two plugins as I am not finding any documentation on them any where.  What they doing??? Whats their purpose???

```
var definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.BUILD_DEV || 'true')),
    __PRERELEASE__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.BUILD_PRERELEASE || 'false'))
 });

 var commonsPlugin = new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DefinePlugin in Webpack is used to inject global variables while webpack is compiling. I am guessing that the `__DEV__` property is used in your project to get the building environment (production, test, development...). Same could go for the `__PRERELEASE__` property. These are custom variables that may be used by Webpack during compilation.

As for the CommonsPlugin, it is used to divide your code into separate files (for instance, app.js = your custom code, vendor.js = external libraries). This is useful in development, when debugging, as you do not need all your libraries in your .map file when looking for an error in your own code.